# Identify ancestor/descendant involving daemonized processes

Tags: process

Is there a way to identify ancestor/descendant processes that's robust in that it works through daemonization? Consider this example:

- PID 123 forks into PID 124
- PID 124 calls setsid
- PID 124 forks into PID 125
- PID 124 exits
- PID 123 waits on PID 124

How can I now establish that PID 125 is a descendant of PID 123? Obviously, parent PID won't work (the parent will be 1 due to PID 124 exiting), and neither will SID (it will be 124, which has died and been reaped, so there's no information available on it).

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do it using just the numeric ID fields. On Linux this can be tackled using control groups (cgroups) because they are hierarchical and a process can't escape its cgroup.

That's why traditional init systems had no reliable way of determining which processes were started by a particular service and thus no reliable way of killing them, unlike systemd which relies on cgroups to keep track of the process tree.